# Question about using the Telnet.

Tags: telnet

How can I enable the Telnet service on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Can somebody include a detailed description about the needed packages and configurations and use it and what are it's advantages?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/799289/how-to-install-telnet-client-on-ubuntu-16/882032 "what are it's advantages?" - too broad, advantages over what for what purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

There is zero advantages.

It's unencrypted, and obsolete. SSH has taken over. SSH is secure, and it supports secure file transfer in addition to secure login.

There's zero reasons to deploy telnet today. Even the simplest computers running a general purpose OS has CPU and RAM enough to host a ssh daemon.

In short: you do not want to enable telnet, and if you believe you want to enable telnet you are mistaken.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say but telnet may be reasonable on a LAN and you can watch star wars over telnet - `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`

Comment: I don't see why. ssh is as reasonable, and it is easier to use the same protocol everywhere you do remote logins. And by all means, feel free to watch star wars.